# Turning date into integers in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R and I have a month column and a day column containing characters like "jan", "feb", or "mar" for months or "mon", "tue" or "wed" for days. I would like to find a way to convert both columns into integers ranging from 1 to 12 for months and 1 to 7 for days. I have tried built-in functions like month.abb but when I try using match with the column for months it just returns a list of NA. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Post a sample of your data using `dput`.

Comment: How do I do that? Isn't there just a built-in R function I can use that would work all the time?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610.

Comment: `month.abb` fails because month names start with a capital letter in English.  Your data doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general method would be to define a factor with the levels you want, and then turn it into an integer. See reprex underneath.

This would also work for weekdays.

```r
months <- c(
  "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", 
  "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "des"
  )

x <- sample(months, 10, replace = TRUE)

x
#>  [1] "sep" "oct" "mar" "jun" "oct" "mar" "apr" "aug" "jul" "sep"

as.integer(factor(x, levels = months))
#>  [1]  9 10  3  6 10  3  4  8  7  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match`:

```r
match(c("jan", "feb", "may"), tolower(month.abb))
match(c("mon", "tue", "thur"), c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thur", "fri", "sat", "sun"))
```